# Asynchronous Handling of Observables

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

I am fairly new to rxjs and reactive programming in general and I have got a fair bit of grey area surrounding the async handling of observables.

I have a straight forward scenario with routing a user to my web-app after user clicks login.

The flow is as follows:
Step 1: User clicks login.
Step 2: In the handler function for the login button - onSuccess, I get the state of profile details updated for the current user. 
Step 3: Navigate to profile page or Main Dashboard page based on weather the details are updated or not.

Following is my LoginHandler:

```
handleLogin = async (result: NetworkResult<AccessTokenResult>) => {
    performOnNetworkResult(result, {
      onSuccess:  () => {
         this.profileService.isdetailupdated //gets the state of details from profile service
          .pipe(
            takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe),
          )
          .subscribe(
             details=> {
               //routing based on boolean details
               if (details !== null && details) {
                  this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
               } else if (details !== null && !details ) {
                  this.router.navigate(['/profile']);
               }
             }
          );
    });
  };
```

And here is a short snapshot of the service code that updates `isdetailsupdated`

```
 fetchProfile = () => {
      return this.profileApiService.getProfile().pipe(
        tap(profileResult =>
          performOnNetworkResult(profileResult, {
            onSuccess: () => {
              this.profileValue = profileResult.value; //this one resolves a while after my login on success is executed
              if (this.profileValue !== null && this.profileValue.phoneNumber !== null && this.profileValue.address !== null) {
                this.isdetailupdated.next(true);
              } else {
                this.isdetailupdated.next(false);
              }

              }
        }
  }))
```

Initially, I had `isdetailupdated` from `profileService` setup as an **observable** and my subscribe section wouldn't trigger at all because there is a delay for `profileservice` to resolve `isdetailsUpdated` and once it is resolved, my observable subscribe is not asynchronously invoked. (why!?)

I was expecting the subscribe for an observable to get triggered every time the observable has a new value but that wasn't happening.

I got around this issue by converting `profileService.isdetailupdated` to a **ReplaySubject**. With a ReplaySubject, the subscribe actually waits for it to get an initial value and my routing works as expected (I couldn't use a **BehaviourSubject** for the reason that it would have an initial value causing my logic to fail, **ReplaySubject** doesn't need an initial value and in my case I made it to only update once my `profileService` resolves the state of `detailsToBeUpdated`)

All Cool, problem solved. Except, I have a hard time processing all of this in my head. This felt like a very common use-case and I am really not sure if I am doing too much with a ReplaySubject etc. So here are my questions:

***1. Why isn't the subscribe of an observable invoked asynchronously after the observable has a new value? 

2. If we need to use ReplaySubjects to asynchronously handle observables, why is it so obscure in the documentation? [Learnrxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects) defines ReplaySubjects as follows:***

> ReplaySubject - Emits specified number of last emitted values (a replay) to new subscriber

which really isn't instructive to the behavior I am using it for.

**3. Is there a more elegant way to solve my scenario, which is *loginhandler function waiting for an observable to resolve before routing*?**

Comment: If a ReplaySubject solves your problem, your problem probably was that you subscribed **after** the observable already emitted a value. `subscribe` won't receive a value in that case. Your problem is `this.profileService.isdetailupdated` so you should post the code for that.

Comment: I have updated the service code in the question. Not sure if it is a problem of subscription **after** observable emitting, because I know from debugging that the service code is actually executed after the login successhandler.

Comment: If you subscribe to an observable and it emits something (after you subscribed) you'll receive the value in subscribe. So if you don't receive a value you subscribed to late (after the observable emitted). Other than that you still haven't posted enough code to get the full picture. Where is `this.isdetailupdated` defined? When is `fetchProfile` called?

Comment: Hmm, appreciate your response here. I got your point about subscribing after observable emitting.  I suspect that isn't the case here because the onSuccess of fetchProfile is resolved sometime after the execution of the onSuccess of login handler. I defined `isdetailsupdated` as a class level variable in the service component. fetchprofile is invoked after login button is clicked.